# MY SQL SYNTAX ERROR HOW TO FIX IN SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring, boot

Getting ERROR: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  `emp.employeeMangement.api.DTO.ResponseDTO(emp.empName,emp.gender,emp.email,emp at line 1`

```
@Query(value = "select NEW com.emp.employeeMangement.api.DTO.ResponseDTO("  +
        `"emp.empName," +
        "emp.gender," +
        "emp.email," +
        "emp.empCode," +
        "att.noOfAbsent," +
        "att.noOfPresent," +
        "att.month," +
        "att.noOfDaysInMonth," +
        "sal.salAmount," +
        "round(@per_day\\:=sal.salAmount/att.noOfDaysInMonth) as salperday," +
        "round(att.noOfPresent*@per_day) as Salarycurrentmonth " +
        ") " +
        "from Employee as emp " +
        "join Attendence as att " +
        "on emp.emp_id=att.cp_fk" +
        " left join Salary as sal " +
        "on sal.emp_id_fk=emp.emp_id",nativeQuery = true)
List<ResponseDTO> getInfoInExcel();
```

Comment: I think `emp.employeeMangement.api.DTO` is package name and package names only have lowercase letters so change `emp.employeeMangement.api.DTO.ResponseDTO` to `emp.employeemangement.api.dto.ResponseDTO` and try again.

Comment: Thanks @Pawan Bishnoi
. but I tried it not solved getting same error only.

Comment: try adding this to `application.properties` to print the exact query: `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

Comment: looks like you have set `nativeQuery = true` are your column names in the table camel case or with underscore?  i.e. is the column name `empName` or `emp_name`?

Comment: Yes I have removed native query since i am not using now column names in the table but now getting  other error like  :
Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.emp.employeeMangement.api.Repository.EmployeeRepository.getInfoInExcel(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.emp.employeeMangement.api.Repository.EmployeeRepository.getInfoInExcel()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List